# Error:An unknown error occurred while invoking the service metadata component. Failed to generate service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

When trying to use .net core 2.1 rc1 to add a service reference for WCF, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Error:An unknown error occurred while invoking the service metadata component. Failed to generate service reference
```

I have checked and the only security in place is Transport, no message security.

The logs are as follows:

```
[05/24/2018 12:28:28],59,Importing web service metadata ...

[05/24/2018 12:28:28],27,Number of service endpoints found: 2

[05/24/2018 12:28:28],9,Scaffolding service reference code ...

[05/24/2018 12:28:28],71,Executing command [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_May_24_12_28_28\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet new console --no-restore --force --type project --language C# --output . --name svcutil_starter"

[05/24/2018 12:28:30],9,Executing command [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_May_24_12_28_28\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet restore --ignore-failed-sources"

[05/24/2018 12:28:31],35,Executing command [C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_May_24_12_28_28\svcutil_starter]
 "dotnet "svcutil" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Users\me\\.nuget\packages" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2018_May_24_12_28_28\SvcUtilParams.txt""

[05/24/2018 12:28:32],52,An unknown error occurred while invoking the service metadata component.
Failed to generate service reference.

[05/24/2018 12:28:32],11,Done.
```

Comment: Could you try using the 2.1 RTM versions from the early access links? https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads

Comment: Also, which service are you trying to add? does the WSDL contain imports to other XSDs? (for some services, querying with `?singleWsdl` instead of `?wsdl` works to get wsdl files)

Comment: I will try the singleWsdl parameter but it does not contain other XSDs.

I'll have a look at the RTM versions.

Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: SingleWSDL didn't work. I don't think the Tool knows how to use it.
I'm just looking now at these early access downloads.

Comment: Can you share the wsdl? does it contain import xsd declarations?

Comment: Not publicly no. It doesn't import any XSD declarations, but I wondered if this caused any issues; <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/WebServices/">

Comment: I am getting the same error for https://webservice.nada.com/vehicles/secure/securelogin.asmx?WSDL - give a try if you need a sample to reproduce

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a temporary solution to this issue I have added a new Project to my solution, set it to Asp Core 1.1 and added the connected service that way which appears to work.

It would seem 2.1 is broken currently and I'll have to wait for updates before doing it directly in my Project.

Edit: Thanks to User3130628. This has now been fixed and appears to be working, even in VS 15.7.5.

I suspect the Core framework has been updated and this has corrected the issue.

Comment: Worked for me when I switched the framework target from .NET Core 2.1 back to .NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Till 2018-07-31, it still has problems for NET Core 2.1.x to add a service reference for WCF in VS2017 (v15.7.5). You can create Net 2.0.x project to create the connected service, it'll work perfect. Then copy the 'Connected Services' sub-directory in project to new NET core v2.1.x project.

Installs the following packages via NuGet such as this image:

NuGet Packages for Connected Services
[image]

Compiled successfully in NET Core 2.1.x project.

Comment: an update to .net Core 2.2 (netcoreapp2.2) will solve this. no need for copy files if ur project does not depend on 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

As of today VS2017 15.8.1 it seems to be working again with .Net core 2.1.401

Comment: I will try this out later and if correct I will update the solution.

Comment: You are correct, this has now worked as expected. Original solution updated.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, all I needed to do was update Visual Studio (didn't work in VS2017 15.7.0, now works after update to VS2017 15.9.5).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this worked for me:

- Created second Temp new project targeted to .Net Core 2.0 (in another instance of VS)
- Make service reference call (Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider) with .wsdl uri
- Open 1st project (target project targetted to .Net Core 2.1) and add the service reference the same way.

Not sure why this worked. Without creating the second solution in a different instance of Visual Studio, it was not working.

Hope this helps.